# Extract images from an eml file

Tags: python, gmail, extract, eml

I was looking for an appropriate way to get a specific image from an eml file, but unfortunately, I always get text data without images!

Here is the code I used but it gives me just text data :

```
from email.parser import BytesParser
from email import policy

with open(em, 'rb') as fp:
    name = fp.name  # Get file name
    msg = BytesParser(policy=policy.default).parse(fp)
data = msg.get_body(preferencelist=('plain')).get_content()
print(data)
fp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

do you find any way to solve this？ I'm eager to know the method

Comment: The content of your post was mentioning you were having a similar issue and asking a question yourself. This would be better posted as a comment to the question and not as an answer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31208776)